# External CSS downloaded in chrome but not reflected

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome

I have an external CSS style which is downloaded in chrome but not reflected. When I do it manually change stylesheet in inline its reflected. Its working fine in Firefox browser.

Loaded the style sheet in below format:

```
if (domainURL != '') {
    link = document.createElement('LINK');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = domainURL;
    link.type = 'text/css';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

I also tried the below solutions but none of them worked.

1. refresh
2. clearing cache
3. adding version in the style link (ex: https://tel.org.css?v=1.111)

Please someone help me to fix this chrome browser issue.

Comment: “[mre], or it didn’t happen.”

Comment: Maybe Chrome doesn’t like that you are creating a `LINK` element, when it should be a `link` element?

Comment: @CBroe it will cause the loading but when do inline edit it works in chrome how?

Comment: Inline editing probably works differently, maybe more in an innerHTML-like way. Again: Please present a proper reproducible example of your issue, if you want help.

Comment: ok will add my site. you can inspect and check

Comment: is it a 3rd party resource? is it on the same domain? HTTP headers could be enough to block this. Could we see a live example of the issue?

Comment: @Sheraff check this one in chrome..inspect to find css with the domain name...thats only not applied correctly..but in mozila the same works

Comment: @Sheraff if u run the link in both mozila and chrome u will know the difference

Comment: I see the difference visually. Which CSS file am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess so far is that the CSS file isn't being applied because it has a wrong [HTTP header `content-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) whose value should be a [mime-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) with an encoding parameter (`text/css; charset: UTF-8`) but instead it is an unknown value (`css`).

It seems that Firefox overrides the wrong content-type header and sniffs (guesses) the info (since there is no `x-content-type-options: nosniff` it's allowed). And Chrome probably instead respects the header "if it's there it must be for a reason" and thus doesn't know what to do with a file of an unknown type.

To test this diagnostics, you should try and either:

- load another CSS file (hosted somewhere else if possible, since it's probably the server setting a wrong header). It doesn't have to be pretty, just to show whether it's applied.
- change the header if you can. Either fix content-type or remove it (and let the browser sniff the mime-type, not ideal for security, but will work).
- create the stylesheet in JS:

  ```js
  fetch('your-css-file.css')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(styleString => {
          const style = document.createElement('style')
          style.textContent = styleString
          document.head.append(style)
      })
  ```

---

I tested myself the 3rd solution (fetch in JS and create a stylesheet with the text response) and it works. However, it then tries to download an image because of the following rule:

```css
.logo { 
  background-image:  url(../logo/images6.1624696593222.jpg);
```

and, same as before, I got a wrong content-type header:

```
Request URL: https://greatone11.aroscop.org/logo/images6.1624696593222.jpg
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
server: nginx/1.18.0
x-powered-by: Express
```

It seems that you have [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) as your server and [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as your reverse proxy. And one of these is messing with your headers. My bet would be on Express, since it's probably set up for angular, and you're trying to do some not-very-angular-things right here!

Comment: link.type = 'text/css; charset: UTF-8'  like this i should add in my code or where should i add the content type?

Comment: @Harifrais `content-type` is a HTTP header. You cannot set it from inside javascript, it's the server's job to set it.

Comment: that means how to i fix this one? i dont have any idea

Comment: @Harifrais i added 3 possible things you can try to my answer. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: 3rd point solves my problem..i will check once dynamically and  will give upvote

Comment: @Harifrais cool, tell me if you have any more questions. But I think you're going to run into more issues if you don't fix your Express server (I updated my response with more info I could find).

Comment: actullay i dont use any express server.

Comment: @Harifrais you definitely do, it's in the HTTP headers! Maybe you didn't set it up yourself, but it's somewhere between the code you write and the files I receive!

Comment: Ya may be i need to check in s3 bucket or cdn. because the files are served from there only

Comment: @Harifrais I did already because I think it's a valid inquiry. However your question is not very clear (because the problem itself wasn't, so it's not entirely your fault), and the solution required some work and not just repeating something from somewhere else. For these 2 reasons, people have downvoted you.